# Combination of SVD perturbation

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, signal-processing, svd

To apply the combination of SVD perturbation:

```
I = imread('image.jpg');
Ibw = single(im2double(I));
[U S V] = svd(Ibw);
% calculate derviced image
P = U * power(S, i) * V'; % where i is between 1 and 2
%To compute the combined image of SVD perturbations:
J = (single(I) + (alpha*P))/(1+alpha); % where alpha is between 0 and 1
```

I applied this method to a specific face recognition model and I noticed the accuracy was highly increased!! So it is very efficient!. Interestingly,  I used the value **i=3/4** and **alpha=0.25** according to a paper that was published in a journal in 2012 in which the authors used `i=3/4` and `alpha=0.25`. But I didn't make attention that `i` must be between `1 and 2`! (I don't know if the authors make an error of dictation or they in fact used the value 3/4). So I tried to change the value of i to a value greater than 1, the accuracy decreased!!. So can I use the value 3/4 ? If yes, how can I argument therefore my approach?

The paper that I read is entitled "Enhanced SVD based face recognition". In page 3, they used the value i=3/4. 
(http://www.oalib.com/paper/2050079)

Kindly I need your help and opinions. Any help will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea to have the value between one and two is to magnify the singular values to make them invariant to illumination changes.

Refer to this paper: A New Face Recognition Method based on SVD Perturbation for Single Example Image per Person: Daoqiang Zhang,Songcan Chen,and Zhi-Hua Zhou

Note that when n equals to 1, the derived image P is equivalent to the original image I . If we 
choose n>1, then the singular values satisfying s_i > 1 will be magnified. Thus the reconstructed 
image P emphasizes the contribution of the large singular values, while restraining that of the 
small ones. So by integrating P into I , we get a combined image J which keeps the main 
information of the original image and is expected to work better against minor changes of 
expression, illumination and occlusions.

My take:
When you scale the singular values in the exponent, you are basically introducing a non-linearity, so its possible that for a specific dataset, scaling down the singular values may be beneficial. Its like adjusting the gamma correction factor in a monitor.

Comment: First thank you for your answer. But the paper I read is "Enhanced SVD Bsed Face Recognition" not the paper that you wrote in the answer. But can I understand that it is possible to take the value of "i" to 3/4 which is not in the interval [1,2] ?

Comment: I read the paper which you had cited, which is basically a minor update to the paper by Zhang et. al. The intuition behind choosing the values between 1 and 2 is described by Zhang et. al.

Comment: Ah so it is not an error of dictation in the paper ? they indeed used the value 3/4 ?